# ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name <ClassName>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, precompile, execjs

I've created a JavaScript class (named as `BarChart`) that have constructor and several methods init.

I executed below command to pre-compile assets for production environment but got error.

Command used to pre-compiling assets: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace`

Error backtrace:

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (BarChart) (line: 24472, col: 6, pos: 952834)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:3623:11948)
    at js_error (<eval>:3623:12167)
    at croak (<eval>:3623:22038)
    at token_error (<eval>:3623:22175)
    at unexpected (<eval>:3623:22263)
    at semicolon (<eval>:3623:22781)
    at simple_statement (<eval>:3623:25959)
    at <eval>:3623:23747
    at <eval>:3623:22954
    at <eval>:3624:3759
    at Object.parse (<eval>:3624:3999)
    at parse (<eval>:3958:22)
```

Javascript class which throws error is written like:

```
class BarChart
{
    // code goes here
}
```

I've added `therubyracer` and `execjs` gem in Gemfile.

`Ruby`: 2.2.5

`Rails`: 3.2.2`

PS: I've checked several questions of this type in SO, but none of the issue is related to **JavaScript `class`**.

Comment: Seems like there're two requests to close question. Can someone please explain me the reason of the **close** question request? I didn't found JS class related issue yet.

Comment: I voted to close it because I do not understand it - it is unclear to me. Imagine yourself on the place of someone who has no slightest clue of your problem and describe it in a way one could understand it. The better (do not confuse with "the more") you describe the issue, the higher chances to get proper answer.

Comment: Check this link. Hope this will help you.  http://www.academytimes.com/solved/7392211522/rails-5-heorku-deploy-error-execjsprogramerror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @CodeLღver Thanks for your answer but I've already checked that and it does not solve my error.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I've updated the question, please check. BTW, thanks for providing the reason for closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd written the JavaScript in `ES6` and rails 3 shows error while `ES6` code. All the methods of using `ES6` in rails is not for rails 3. So I converted ES6 to ES5 code.

Comment: rails, still use es5 :(

Comment: Nope, you can use ES(6/7) syntax for rails 5 and after.

Comment: I could not, eg using `let` would not work. Rails 6.0.0.1. `ExecJS` compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In your BarChart js file, change all the `let` to `var`.
Then the precompile should go successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 5 I resolved the issue renaming files from .js to .js.es6. Weirdly it my staging deploy worked and my production deploy did not.